# How can I add the thousands comma separator to this string format: (%0.2f)?

Tags: string-formatting, openrpt

[image]

I am working with OpenRPT report writer and am trying to add the thousands comma separator for a field and the example they provide is %0.2f which I believe to be Python syntax.  This is formatting the value as a float with 2 digit precision; however, I do not have thousand comma separation.  How can I adjust the format mask to allow for thousand comma separation?  I have attached an image of the dialog.

Sample input: `16119.20`

Desired output: `16,119.20`

Comment: Hi. Can you supply a sample input and desired output? Cheers.

Comment: Input: 16119.20
Desired Output: $16,119.20

Comment: I see. I edited your post with sample input and desired output for clearer future reference.

Answer (score 11):

You mean something like this?

```
>>> "{:,.2f}".format(12345678.23456)
'12,345,678.23'
```

Comment: That will not work for the application I am working in, OpenRPT.  I am shooting in the dark as I haven't found much documentation on what exact syntax it is expecting for string formatting.

Comment: When I add a field to the report, go to the field properties, I have a text field where I can specify a string format and their provided example is: %0.2f
That could span several programming languages, however.

Comment: @Gryphoenix I don't think the old-style formatting(%) supports this feature.

Comment: Which is the most recent version of Python which supports it?

Comment: `"{1} xxx {0}".format("5", "2.3")` will output: `5 xxx 2.3` this I understand, `"{:,.2f}"` I couldn't get :( except that `f` suffix means `format()` argument should be `float` : What does mean by `:,.2` **?**

Answer (score 2):

You can add a comma with the [locale module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html):

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")  
'English_United States.1252'  
>>> locale.format('%0.2f', 16119.2, True)  
'16,119.20'
```

The has the added benefit of swapping periods and commas for those cultures that do so.